# How to store visitors of a particular entry in database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I am developing a survey application in ASP.NET. I have three table and their columns as follows:-

**Members** ( id, email, Name, Password, type(user or admin) )

**Survey** ( id, ownerId, Name, surveyHits(how many times it is filled) )

**Question** ( id, SurveyId, ...some other fields)

I store every visitor who visits a survey in Members table.

**Now what I need is that , I want to associate all visitors of a survey to the survey itself, so that no body can do a survey twice**.

What should I do, or exactly, how should I save and track visitors of a particular survey?

I can change the Data Base schema too, if required...

**EDIT :-**

Creating a new table storing combination of "surveyId" and "memberId" as primary key is a solution but,

Suppose I have a 1,000 surveys and 10,000 members.  And every member has filled in every survey, so I'll be keeping **10 Million** records against just 11 Thousand records.
Can't I have some more efficient solution?

Comment: Is there a semantical difference between Visitor and Member?

Comment: No. Every one is a member.

Comment: @Mahroz According to your edit: You want to store 10 million information. 10 million rows is the standard way to do it. Do not think about hdd space (it will take like 50-100mb, this is really nothing. Even 20 years ago that would be ok.). If you got 10000 people to fill in 1000 surveys, you are already golden. Do not try to denormalize data (here it means: put more than 1 information in one column). Just don't.

Comment: I got the point. Now doing it in @EagleRainbow way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to introduce a new DB table which tracks the combination between Members and Surveys.

```
CREATE TABLE FilledSurveys (
   MemberId as int not null,
   SurveyId as int not null,
   foreign key (MemberId) references Member(id) on update cascade,
   foreign key (SurveyId) references Survey(id) on update cascade,
   primary key (MemberId, SurveyId)
);
```

To ensure consistency, you should make use of [foreign key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) relationships (keep in mind that this might require to use the InnoDB engine). This table may also make the - for me somewhat - strange persisted attribute `surveyHits` of `Survey` obsolete, as the [same data can be calculated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html) on the
fly via

```
SELECT SurveyId, count(*) as surveyHits
   FROM FilledSurveys 
   GROUP BY SurveyId
```

However, please be careful: Whilst before your database was quite anonymous and Members/Visitors could not be tracked to their survey results - this will be gone now: There is a clear and persisted relationship between Surveys and Members.

Comment: Suppose I have a 1,000 surveys and 10,000 members.  And every member has filled in every survey, so I'll be keeping **10 Million** records against just 11 Thousand records.
Can't I have some more efficient solution?

Answer (score 2):

By efficient do you mean space efficient?  Because what EagleRainbow suggests is probably the most time efficient.  If you're looking for space efficient, then it depends on what constraints (if any) you can place on how members do surveys.

If there's a strict ordering e.g. members need to do surveys in id order, or created_dtm order etc, then you could store on the member the last survey that they've done.

If there's no ordering, then you could denormalise the table from EagleRainbow's suggestion a bit, but it will need more code and take longer to record each survey.  You could store ranges of contiguous survey ids (or dtms, or some other unique survey identifier) that have been done.  You then merge these records as soon as you can, and delete redundant records.

Assuming you're recording surveys done by their id, then the table could look like this:

**CompletedSurveyRange**
@range_id
member_id
min_survey_id
max_survey_id

If member 8765 starts by doing survey 333, then you create the record:

(range_id=1000, member_id=8765, min_survey_id=333, max_survey_id=333).

Ignoring any other members, imagine that they next do survey 335.  As there's a gap (334) between the surveys already recorded and the new one, you need to create a new record:

(1001, 8765, 335, 335).

Imagine that the next survey done is 332.  This can be added onto the first record, as it is an adjacent survey.  So you end up with these records:

(1000, 8765, 332, 333)
(1001, 8765, 335, 335)

I'll skip over the details, but imagine that they do surveys 336-340 in order, and so record 1001 gets its max value incremented each time, and you end up with:

(1000, 8765, 332, 333)
(1001, 8765, 335, 340)

Then they do survey 334.  This bridges the gap between record 1000 and record 1001, so you can merge them and delete one of them (it doesn't really matter which - I'll arbitrarily keep the lower id).  You end up with:

(1000, 8765, 332, 340)
(1001, 8765, 335, 340) <= deleted

If you have N surveys, then you will have at most N/2 live records per member (where they have completed N/2 surveys, where the ids are every other id in the list).  As soon as they complete one further survey, it will go down to (N/2)-1 as one record will be merged into another and so deleted.  If they completed surveys in a pattern other than every other one, then doing N/2 surveys will need fewer than N/2 records and it will never grow greater than N/2.

Comment: +1 for your effort on the entire discussion of space complexity. However, i personally would say that this is overengineering: First of all, I would like to see such a system live with 1,000 active surveys + 10,000 members having a participation rate of 100%. Assuming that completing a survey only takes 5 mins. each, to build up such a system, it would cost ~578 PDs (i.e. about 3 person-years). Moreover, assuming that the IDs are all 32 bit integers, the data volume to store would be 80 MB - an amount which a modern desktop PC can read from disk in less than 1s (and even faster in memory).

Comment: I agree - it's not the way I would do it (I would go with the approach you described), but he seemed to think it was too inefficient (having said that twice).  So, this is the only kind of alternative I could think of.